# How to replace GNOME with Cinnamon in Fedora19

Tags: fedora, cinnamon

I am having Fedora19 with GNOME interface. I am not at all comfortable with GNOME3 and want to remove it completely and use Cinnamon instead.

Can i do that?

I am asking this, because i have heard that Cinnamon will use some repositories of GNOME.

Is there any safe way of doing this without breaking any repositories. Please guide

Comment: Why do you want to remove Gnome? You can just install Cinnamon andnuse it and leave Gnome as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone, lot of people not liking the gnome style/

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-cinnamon-desktop-on-fedora-18

:D